# AWS lambda serverless `schedule` event creation error: LimitExceededException

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm getting the following error while trying to `sls deploy` a function with a `schedule` event:

```
An error occurred: SupWorldEventsRuleSchedule1 - The requested 
resource exceeds the maximum number allowed. (Service: 
AmazonCloudWatchEvents; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 
LimitExceededException; Request ID: f39cee40-a651-11e8-a111-97a9e3d0f938).
```

Config:

```
functions:
  supWorld:
    handler: dist/handlers/index.helloWorld
    events:
      - schedule:
          rate: cron(*/10 * * * ? *)
          enabled: true
```

The strange aspect of this error is that there are no other `schedule` events associated with this lambda stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How many Cloudwatch rules are there already in your account? By default you can only have 100: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/cloudwatch_limits_cwe.html

If I had to guess the error is occurring because you have reached the limit on your account

Comment: Ah. The limit is per account, not per lambda. Thank you!

Comment: We recently hit this limit on our project. Considering every scheduled event and step function that you have creates its own CloudWatch Event, we are already maxing out the limit for our account early in our product's lifetime. AWS is willing to expand our limit but for a significant cost, so we are trying to figure out what other options we have. I'm amazed this isn't a more common issue given how liberal Serverless is with creating CloudWatch Events.